# "Высоко(-) и низкоуглеродистая сталь": нужен ли дефис?

Tags: пунктуация

"Высоко(-) и низкоуглеродистая сталь" — нужен ли тут дефис после слова "Высоко", как, например, в выражении "теле- и радиокоммуникация"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если слово образовано на основе словосочетания, то оно пишется слитно: ремонт вагонов - вагоноремонтный, низкий углерод - низкоуглеродный (низкоуглеродистая). Что касается оформления записи "Высоко(-) ", то,конечно, дефис нужен: аудио- и видеотехника.

Comment: Угу. Это так называемый "висячий дефис".